# Root access to Ubuntu when you have a access to sudoer's desktop, but not to his root password

Tags: security, root

I did the following steps.

1. `mv ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring.bakup`
2. Reboot computer
3. Choose `advanced options` -> `recovery` -> `boot as root`

This got me to root terminal. Password was not required.

Now I can do whatever I want, e.i. format the disk. Or I can do better. I've created a new `unwanted_user` and added it to sudoers group. Moved the keyring from `login.keyring.bakup` to `login.keyring`, while keeping permissions. Rebooted Ubuntu one more time. I could have installed SSH-server, connect to this computer from a remote location, do my stuff, cleanup logs and delete the `unwanted_user`.

Sure, an admin in a government security office would lock his computer, notice that the computer is now at a login screen, check logs, have surveillance cameras, etc.

But what if I am a layman, hiding my private documents in a folder, owned by root? Anyone familiar with Linux can repeat these steps. Is this a feature or a bug. Can I disable this unwanted keyring service? I've uninstalled the `seahorse`, but the same steps worked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This got me to root terminal. Password was not required.
>
> ...
>
> But what if I am a layman, hiding my private documents in a folder, owned by root? Anyone familiar with Linux can repeat these steps. Is this a feature or a bug.

If you have physical access to a computer you can always find a way to access (and change) unencrypted data on it. This isn't really related to the login keyring, once you boot in the [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub), you are root and you can do whatever you want, you don't need to do anything with the login keyring. You can add [password protection to GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) to make sure your system can't be booted in a single user mode, but simply booting from a Live USB will give you the same full access.

If you want to hide your files, don't hide them in a folder owned by root, [encrypt your disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019) and if other people have access to your computer, never leave it without locking the screen or shutting it down.

Comment: Well, then why do we bother with permissions and user privileges if a simple `advanced boot settings` -> `boot as a root` grants you root access to the computer? You cannot alter system files on Windows 10 without elevating the privilege (with password).

Comment: `...Will give you the same root access if you can physically connect the harddrive to another computer...`. In Windows I can store my computer in a locked case with no access to plug LiveOS. In Ubuntu you can.

Comment: Got it, I should add a password protection of GRUB, which is off by default. Thank you, answer accepted.

Comment: You still want to limit what users and process can do when logged in to the system (or running on the system in case of applications). You don't want a random JS script running in Firefox to be able to access your system files. And if you think about other use cases than a personal desktop, with servers users don't have physical access to the machine.

Comment: @sixtytrees the main point is what Vojtech says in the first paragraph: if you have physical access to the computer, then the computer is considered compromised. For example, I can simply remove the hard drive, put it into my computer where I have root access and do whatever I want. There is no security that can protect from an attacker with physical access to the machine. All you can do is make it slightly harder.

Comment: @terdon What if you have physical access to the mouse and the keyboard, but no access to 5 minutes reboot-LiveOS session? Windows says " you are protected". Ubuntu says "you are screwed regardless, you should have kept your computer unpowered in a safe".

Comment: @sixtytrees if Windows tells you you are protected, it is lying. This is a fundamental concept in computer security: [if you have physical access to the machine, you can consider it compromised](https://www.everything2.com/title/If+an+attacker+has+physical+access%252C+your+system+is+already+compromised). This has nothing to do with the OS, grub isn't part of the OS: as long as you can boot into another system (which you can if you have access) then there's nothing any operating system can do apart from slow you down, at best.

Comment: @terdon I am not fighting against the State. My opponent is my wife/friend/colleague  (geek capable, but without the computational resources of a State) that can access computer's power button and the keyboard, but no access to the HDD. I thought that a file with root access privileges with my StackExchange and gmail passwords is not readable under Ubuntu. I thought that my Ubuntu was good enough to protect my date. It was not. Stock mobile devices (iPhone/Android) are good enough though.

Comment: If they're encrypted, yes. But a capable geek knows how to boot a machine from a USB live OS image, @sixtytrees, so will be able to boot your computer under a different OS and access all your data. If you want protection from a minimally capable geek on any operating system, you should encrypt.

Comment: A `capable geek` with access to reboot button and a keyboard, but not the HDD and not to USB port (this is my case) would have troubles root accessing my Ubuntu, provided that the GRUB and the BIOS are both password protected.  Problem solved, let us not harp on this.